# How can I factor our my shell scripts inside my .ebextensions directory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm customising the elastic beanstalk host machine by executing some shell commands.

I have this working fine when the commands are embedded in an ebextension config script.  But I want to write my customisation stuff in normal shell script files, instead of being embedded in YAML syntax that my editor doesn't understand.

So this works:

`.ebextensions/01_do_stuff.config`:

```
commands:
  01echostuff:
    ignoreErrors: false
    command: |
      echo "Do a bunch of elaborate stuff"
```

But I'd rather break my customisation stuff out into a proper shell script and then just launch it with an ebextension config command.

`.ebextensions/myscripts/do_stuff.sh`

```
echo "Do a bunch of elaborate stuff"
```

`.ebextensions/01_do_stuff.config`:

```
commands:
  01echostuff:
    ignoreErrors: false
    command: myscripts/do_stuff.sh
```

Both files (the shell and config) are packaged up in the beanstalk archive file and uploaded as part of the zip archive, I just want beanstalk to deploy my scripts along with the config files from the EB archive and allow me to execute them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is a difference between running [`commands`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) and [`container_commands`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands)
2. You will want to trigger your shell script as `container_commands` which will then be able to access scripts within your application version (zip file)